# How do I stay hidden and undetected while dispatching enemies?

Tags: the-darkness-2

There are occasions where enemies will be oblivious to your presence, and you can kill them stealthily with them noticing. And when playing as the [Darkling](http://thedarkness.wikia.com/wiki/Darkling), you have to move and kill stealthily as the Darkling is easily killed. Also, you can [play as a "ninja"](http://thedarkness.wikia.com/wiki/Inugami) in Vendettas mode, making knowledge regarding stealth approaches useful.

I like doing the the stealth approach whenever possible. A few questions to further this goal:

- Any *tips and tricks* on staying hidden? What are *efficient ways of killing enemies stealthily*? Any **abilities** I should focus on?

How do enemies detect the player character?

- Do the **sounds** you make matter? Do enemies notice gunfire even if it is not hitting them? Does walking slower or crouch-walking help? What about usage of abilities?
- How do **sight and light levels** work? Can you sneak behind enemies? Hide behind objects? Hide in dark places? Being on a different level (a floor up or down)? (Do enemies look up or down?)
- Do enemies have different **"levels" of alertness**?
- **Once you're spotted**, is hiding effective, or will the enemies instantly and constantly know where you're hiding? Do enemies get alerted if you kill one of them, or come across upon a dead body of a person you killed?
- Any enemies with unique behavior when it comes to player detection?
- Does **difficulty** matter?

(Feel free to give partial answers if you only about stealth/detection elements on a particular part of the game, including the [Vendettas campaign](http://thedarkness.wikia.com/wiki/Vendettas).)

[image]

Comment: I can't comment on the darkness 2, but in the darkness (1) you had an ability where you were able to control one of your dark spawn snake thingies and doing that behind an enemy will one shot them and dispose of them silently. Making it your goto stealth killing machine.